# HTML/Javascript Calendar from scratch

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

Is there any resources available that would explain how to build a calendar from scratch without plugins/libraries, that would also allow for events to be implemented into the calendar system?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is off topic here as it's too broad and requests off-site resources. You should do some research, then build something. When you have a problem, ask about that specific issue. You should also try to determine your requirements more specifically than "a calendar" or "calendar system", they can be quite simple or very, very complex. But please don't be discouraged, start coding! ;-)

Comment: Are you only using JavaScript? You can do a pretty decent job using PHP + JavaScript. But like the answer by @RobG it can be simple or very complex, depends on what your use for it will be.